# OpenCV 2.4.3 displays video as grey window

Tags: opencv, video, visual-studio-2012

I have a desktop and laptop running OpenCV 2.4.3 on x64 architectures one on Win 7 and the other on Win 8 both running VS 2012 x64. I've compiled OpenCV on both computers. The desktop running Win 7 displays a video output perfectly while my laptop running the same code Win 8 shows just a grey screen. The rest of the computer vision functions works fine on the laptop. I have to note here that I've installed all video libraries (FFMpeg etc) on both computers quite similarly. Is there something different to be done on my Win 8 machine to show videos?

I tested out the basic video test for PSNR in the samples file and even that fails!

Comment: Try FFDShow decoder. Also, check every input/output file integrity.

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem by copying opencv_ffmpeg243.dll to the directory where the executable was running and it worked. My desktop running Win7 has no issues running the same exec without the dll in the directory.